# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: oledb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456272/multiple-step-ole-db-operation-generated-errors)

Dim NorthWindOledbConnection As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;DataSOurce=SARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=ssp1;InitialCatalog=Sara"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()

rs.Open("select * from SecUserPassword", NorthWindOledbConnection, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic)

i tried to run this above code in visual studio 2008...
it shows the following error........

"Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done"

Help me to proceed further..
thanks in advance