# Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ado

```
Dim NorthWindOledbConnection As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;DataSOurce=SARAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=ssp1;InitialCatalog=Sara"
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset()
rs.Open("select * from SecUserPassword", NorthWindOledbConnection, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic)
```

i tried to run this above code in visual studio 2008 - it shows the following error:

> "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done"

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use ADO in VB.NET. Use ADO.NET.

Other than that, create a proper `Connection` object instead of passing around a string.
And fix your connection string. It's `SSPI`, not `SSP1`. And it's `Data Source`, not `DataSOurce`. And it's `Initial Catalog`, not `InitialCatalog`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very very very old way to access a Database that has been used with Visual Basic 6 and older.

Check to use **ADO.NET** instead of old **ADO**. For example you can use this code that is "similar" to the code you are using (but is not the best way to access the data on VS2008)

```
OleDbConnection con= New OleDbConnection( **Your Connection String** )
con.Open()
Dim command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("select * from SecUserPassword", con)
sqlCommand .CommandType = CommandType.Text

Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = TheCommand.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
    System.Console.Write(reader(** Your Table Field Name** ).ToString())
End While
con.Close()
```

To view how to create a correct connection String see the site http://www.connectionstrings.com/

If you want to access to an SQL Server database also you can use the SQLClient namespace instead the OleDb. For example **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection** instead the **OleDbConnection** to provide better performance for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

The link below is an article that gives a great breakdown of the 6 scenarios this error message can occur:

**Scenario 1 -** Error occurs when trying to insert data into a database

**Scenario 2 -** Error occurs when trying to open an ADO connection

**Scenario 3 -** Error occurs inserting data into Access, where a fieldname has a space

**Scenario 4 -** Error occurs inserting data into Access, when using adLockBatchOptimistic

**Scenario 5 -** Error occurs inserting data into Access, when using Jet.OLEDB.3.51 or ODBC  driver (not Jet.OLEDB.4.0)

**Scenario 6 -** Error occurs when using a Command object and Parameters

http://www.adopenstatic.com/faq/80040e21.asp

Hope it may help others that may be facing the same issue.